# How to analyse moderation of a continuous variable with ANOVA

Tags: interaction, anova

The study is looking at a reading program for children, half the sample given the real treatment program and half a fake program, their score on the reading measure is taken at 3 times, before, during and after the treatment program. There are also 2 potential moderators, maternal depression (scores ranging anywhere betwee 7 and 12) and child behavioral issues (scores ranging anywhere between 25 an 70), both of these variables are measured once. Its my understanding that this is a mixed design but i dont know how to analyse this in SPSS to include the 2 moderators. The question i need to answer is considering the change from baseline to end of treatment, is the difference between
real and fake treatment groups moderated by child behavioural issues or maternal depression. How would i do this in SPSS?

Comment: If the emphasis is strictly on SPSS implementation it will be off topic here. Emphasize the statistical issues.